# How to select the edges in my circle

Tags: edges

[image]

I have a icosphere and in that there are 3 types of 6side star shapes. Large medium and small. In the stars there are edges and i want to remove that edges. I have remove the large star edge selected a single large star edge and shift+g and length and delete all the edges. The same process not working with the small and medium star. I can select manually and delete but i dont want to do it. How can select the edges at few clicks. blend file [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to *Vertex Select*.
2. Select center vertex in small star.
3. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> > *Amount of connecting edges*.
5. Switch to Edge Select and delete them.

[image: Select]